# How to send Ctrl+C to a child bash process on Windows?

Tags: python, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows 10 1709
- Python 3.6

Consider this bash script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ping localhost
```

I start it from Windows command prompt:

```
> bash test.sh
```

When I press Ctrl+C, bash stops and exits cleanly:

```
> bash test.sh
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.156 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.178 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.156/0.167/0.178/0.011 ms
```

However, if I start it from Python script, then it seems that there is no way to stop the child process cleanly. Here is the script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import signal

cmd = ['bash', 'test.sh']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd)

while p.poll() is None:
    try:
        p.wait(2)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        print('{0}: p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)'.format(p.pid))
        p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(e)
print('{0}: {1}'.format(p.pid, p.returncode))
```

Output:

```
> python module1.py
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.193 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.255 ms
2316: p.send_signal(signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)

2316: 3221225786
```

As you can see, the exit code is `3221225786`, aka `0xC000013A` or `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`.
Also, ping process didn't exit by itself, but was rather killed: no summary.

Is there any clean way to stop WSL bash process from Python?

Comment: Why don't you use the `-c` flag to `ping` to specify a count (limit) of packets to send? Then you don't have to rudely kill the child process.

Comment: [taken from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) : have you tried sending it `SIGTERM` ? Or using `terminate()` ?

Comment: @gavinb, The problem is not with `ping` or any other command, but with the way I stop it. I want to stop it gracefully rather than terminating the process.

Comment: @Aserre, See my reply to gavinb. Forcible termination is not a problem. I want to stop the process gracefully.

Comment: If the tool that you're running doesn't provide any mechanism to request it to exit, you're basically left with signals. In order of severity, that would be SIGINT (Control-C), SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

Comment: @gavinb, yes, I agree. Though when I press Ctrl+C with my hands and when I send it programmatically, the process in question behaves differently. It may be a quirk of WSL, as well. In that case I'm out of luck, I guess...